# Error while building Boot to Gecko

Tags: linux, gcc, build, firefox-os

I was trying to build B2G for emulator, but I've got an error.

Environment:

- Ubuntu 12.04.1 x64
- gcc 4.6.3

> Install: out/host/linux-x86/bin/traceview host SharedLib:
>   libGLES_CM_translator
>   (out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libGLES_CM_translator.so) /usr/bin/ld:
>   cannot find -lGL collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make: ***
>   [out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libGLES_CM_translator.so] Error 1
>
> real  1m33.903s user  0m46.539s sys   0m6.088s
>
> > Build failed! <

How do I fix it?

Comment: Run following scripts:
"
#!/bin/bash
#
install_files=`dpkg -L libdrm-dev:i386 libgl1-mesa-dev:i386 libxext-dev:i386 mesa-common-dev:i386`;
for file in $install_files;do
        if [ ! -d $file ];then
                echo $file >> /tmp/GL_i386.log
        fi
done
cd /
cat /tmp/GL_i386.log|xargs tar czf /tmp/GL_i386.tgz
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
sudo tar zxf /tmp/GL_i386.tgz
"

Then build the Android as usual:
$ source ./build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch full_x86-eng
$ make droid -jN

Comment: @m4n07 you should turn that into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Firefox OS build prerequisites](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox_OS/Firefox_OS_build_prerequisites)

> When building on 64-bit Ubuntu, you may find that you need to add symlinks for the 32-bit >versions of libX11.so and libGL.so:
>
> > $ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so
> >
> > $ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-building/3Io1A2ds0DQ/YDqt8na6XDIJ) you should find the solution to your problem.

```
#> sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential zip curl libc6-dev libncurses5-dev:i386 x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev:i386 libreadline6-dev:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dev g++-multilib mingw32 openjdk-6-jdk tofrodos python-markdown libxml2-utils xsltproc zlib1g-dev:i386
```

and then:

```
#> sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so
```

Answer (score 0):

from the [Firefox OS wiki (Firefox OS build prerequisites)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Boot_to_Gecko/Firefox_OS_build_prerequisites?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Mozilla/Boot_to_Gecko/B2G_build_prerequisites), about building on Ubuntu 12.04 x64:

```
$ sudo apt-get install autoconf2.13 bison bzip2 ccache curl flex gawk gcc g++ g++-multilib git ia32-libs lib32ncurses5-dev lib32z1-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libx11-dev make
```

and then,

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error while compiling Android. The following fixed it:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev:i386
```

I did not have to create any symbolic links or anything, just this simple install